# Getting text from the Console

Tags: swift, swift3, stdout

I am trying to access the stdout from the console in a Swift script. For example, if my console looked like this:

[image]

I would be able to access the '0'. Is there a way to do that in Swift or not?

The script won't be what is printing the text to console so I can't just access a variable. This should help explain it:

[image]

The `Running Program` gets the output from the `Other Program` and outputs it to the console. I want to get that output from in the `Script`.

Comment: Which platform? Swift runs on `iOS`, `macOS`, and `Linux`, it's unclear what you mean by access the '0'... access it how?

Comment: @l'L'l either MacOS or Linux. An answer that only handles one would be okey.

Comment: Are you meaning access the output via Terminal, it's not clear.

Comment: @l'L'l, as for accessing '0', I want to be able to get text that was already output the the console previously as a string. Is there some class that has the properties to access the stdout from the console or terminal?

Comment: Get it where though, as in what are you trying to put it into?

Comment: A Swift script. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: If you are already using swift then just save it to a variable; `let var = <whatever is printing zero>`.

Comment: Look into `FileHandle standardOutput`.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried that, but the only thing I noticed is that it did the same thing as `readLine()`.

Comment: @l'L'l I edited the question the further explain what I am doing.

Comment: `readLine()` uses `standardInput`.

Comment: @CalebKleveter If I understand, you want to get, in your app, what is output to stdout, but the process outputting to stdout is not a child process of your app, is that it?

Comment: @EricAya Yes! That is what I am trying to do.